# npm not working without giving an error in windows 7

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to node and my npm has stopped working. It was working fine earlier but stopped working abruptly. It is not giving any error and cursors just wait there. Please help me out here.

Comment: What command are you trying to run? Try running the command with verbose `npm YOURCOMMAND -d`. If you want more detailed verbose then try `npm YOURCOMMAND -ddd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear so don't expect an accurate answer. A reason for that can be the CPU usage or other processes running on the same port number.

I had a similar problem, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411365/app-crashed-in-nodemon).

Try to kill that process or restart your computer

Comment: My CPU is usage is just fine and I also checked if some process is working on same port. The problem is that when i use npm command it doesn't work and it just sits there. For screenshot click [here](https://ibb.co/jaEbLk)